# using openpyxl can't write the duplicate data

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to write data to excel file
this is my test code

```
import openpyxl

def writeToExcel(diskTag,size,route,outputName):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()    
    _fileName=outputName+".xlsx"
    wb.save(_fileName)       
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(_fileName, data_only=True)
    #pageName0="GIF"
    s1 = wb.active      
    #s1 = wb[pageName0]            
    #print(size)
    for i in size:
        s1.cell(size.index(i)+1,1).value = i  
        print(i)
    for i in route:
        s1.cell(route.index(i)+1,2).value = diskTag+i
        print(i)
    #s1.cell(9,1).value = size[8]
    #s1.cell(10,1).value = size[9]
    wb.save(_fileName)
    
diskTag="-"
outputName="test"
size = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,4,1,2]
route = ["a","b","c","d","e","e","d","f","g","r","h","h","f","g","h"]
writeToExcel(diskTag,size,route,outputName)
```

and the file show
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1znO9.png)

the duplicate data is disappear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `size.index(i)` and `route.index(i)`, these will give you the index of the fist occurence of `i` in `size` and `route` respectively.

So when you have duplicate values, you only write it at the location dictated by the index of the first one.

```py
size = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,4,1,2]
size.index(9)  # will always be 8
```

I'm not certain what your goal output is, but if you just want to write `size` and `route` in the columns `A` and `B` of an excel file, I have adapted this from your code.

It uses [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to go through `size` and `route` giving both the current index `i` and the value `v`, and writes similarly to what you did.

There is no need to create a workbook and save it to reopen it right after, what we're writing is just data.

**NB.** I have renamed things slightly to follow [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/).

```py
import openpyxl


def write_to_excel(disk_tag, size, route, output_name):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    for i, v in enumerate(size):
        ws.cell(i + 1, 1).value = v
    for i, v in enumerate(route):
        ws.cell(i + 1, 2).value = disk_tag + v
    wb.save(f"{output_name}.xlsx")


disk_tag = "-"
output_name = "test"
size = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 4, 1, 2]
route = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e", "d", "f", "g", "r", "h", "h", "f", "g", "h"]
write_to_excel(disk_tag, size, route, output_name)
```